# Http request with node?

Tags: javascript, http, node.js, httpclient

How do I make a Http request with node.js that is equivalent to this code:

```
curl -X PUT http://localhost:3000/users/1
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [http client](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html).

Something along these lines:

```
var http = require('http');
var client = http.createClient(3000, 'localhost');
var request = client.request('PUT', '/users/1');
request.write("stuff");
request.end();
request.on("response", function (response) {
    // handle the response
});
```

Answer (score 35):

For others googling this question, the accepted answer is no longer correct and has been deprecated.

The correct method (as of this writing) is to use the http.request method as described here: [nodejitsu example](http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request)

Code example (from the above article, modified to answer the question):

```
var http = require('http');

var options = {
  host: 'localhost',
  path: '/users/1',
  port: 3000,
  method: 'PUT'
};

callback = function(response) {
  var str = '';

  //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
  response.on('data', function (chunk) {
    str += chunk;
  });

  //the whole response has been recieved, so we just print it out here
  response.on('end', function () {
    console.log(str);
  });
}

http.request(options, callback).end();
```

Comment: I don't like this example, as it's just logging to the console. The interesting/hard part though is to process the response string (asynchronously)

Comment: I dont like the example, as it doesnt show how to attach a json object to the message body

Comment: ummmm .... i like this example. changing console.log to response.write() isn't that hard (or interesting) guys, and the OP didn't ask anything about attaching a json object, ask your own question if this one doesn't fit your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var client = http.createClient(1337, 'localhost');
var request = client.request('PUT', '/users/1');
request.write("stuff");
request.end();
request.on("response", function (response) {
response.on('data', function (chunk) {
console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
 });
});
```

Comment: any one have idea, how to handle timeout. If server is not responding in that case ? please comment. <thanks>