# nodejs make request from server

Tags: node.js

I was wondering if it is possible from my nodejs application to post to an API some information because I can't seem to find some example where I can make a request from the nodejs server.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294939/http-request-with-node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) rather than node http. IMO It's definitely more powerful and easier to use

Comment: Or superagent(https://github.com/visionmedia/superagent) or reqwest(https://github.com/ded/reqwest).